# excel VBA error when copying a worksheet from workbook opened using activeworkbook.path

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a summary worksheet from 12 different workbooks into a regional workbook.  I get a debugging error on the line that should copy the worksheet into the regional workbook.  I tried using both the name and worksheet number on both the source and current workbooks. The code is included below.

```
Sub copyfc()

Dim sourceworkbook As Workbook
Dim currentworkbook As Workbook

Set currentworkbook = ThisWorkbook

Set sourceworkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Country Files\BE FC12 BU19.xlsx")

sourceworkbook.Sheets("BE").Copy after:=currentworkbook.Sheets("End")

sourceworkbook.Close


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The line below will place the worksheet at the end:

```
sourceworkbook.Sheets("BE").Copy After:=currentworkbook.Sheets(currentworkbook.Sheets.Count)
```